# What is the official name for SO? With or without a space?

Tags: discussion

Well, there are some possible ways to address this site by name:

---

StackOverflow

Stack Overflow

stackoverflow

stack overflow

---

I was wondering what the way to go is?

On official pages like [Code of Conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) it is addressed by *Stack Overflow* but I've noticed that on many places in answers, questions, comments etc. that is not the case. Another example is the logo of the site.

I'll probably get downvoted into the 5th dimension for this question, as it's obvious from the official way, but please share your opinion. Maybe there are more perspectives to that which I can consider e.g. when welcoming new users, i.e. *"Welcome to Stack Overflow! [...]"*.

Comment: It’s endlessly frustrating to me that Chrome recommends “StackOverflow” as the preferred spelling when I’ve written “Stack Overflow”.

Comment: Use Opera.. Mine recommends "Stack Overflow" when I try "StackOverflow".

Comment: [So far, 72 different spellings have been observed in the wild](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html) (near "`/Stack_Overflow`", second block).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's definitely "Stack Overflow". Yes, lots of people get it wrong, but it's fairly clear in the [trademark guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance):

> There is some confusion around the proper use and context of the Stack Exchange name.
>
> Here are some guidelines:
>
> - ...
> - **Stack Overflow** is a programmer Q&A site on the Stack Exchange Network. As a name, Stack Overflow, is always written "Stack Overflow" (two words, capital letters). The website domain name is always written **stackoverflow.com** (no CamelCase, single word capitalization rules apply). Currently, all Stack Exchange Network sites follow this convention: Server Fault (serverfault.com), Super User (superuser.com), etc.